# $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ action on an affine quadric

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, algebraic-groups

What is an example of an affine quadric $Q\subset  \mathbb C^3$ such that $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ acts transitively  and $Q=SL_2(\mathbb C)/\mathbb C^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by two steps:

1. The group 
   $$
   \mathrm{SO}_{3}(\mathbb{C}) = \{A\in M_{3}(\mathbb{C}) \,|\, AA^{T} = I\}
   $$
   naturally acts on the quadric 
   $$
   Q = \{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{C}^{3}\,|\, x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} =1\}
   $$
   by $(x, y, z)^{T} \mapsto A(x, y, z)^{T}$. This action is transitive, and stabilier of $e_{1} = (1, 0, 0)^{T}$ is 
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \mathbf{0}^{T} \\ \mathbf{0} & g \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   with $g\in \mathrm{SO}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$. So $Q \simeq \mathrm{SO}_{3}(\mathbb{C}) / \mathrm{SO}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$.
2. We have an isomorphism 
   $$
   \mathrm{PSL}_{2}(\mathbb{C}) \simeq \mathrm{SO}_{3}(\mathbb{C}). 
   $$
   This can be obtained by considering adjoint action of $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$, and observing that for $v, w\in \mathfrak{sl}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$, $(v, w) \mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(vw)$ is a bilinear pairing which is invariant under the adjoint action. (For details, see [my note](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12soWvMyVt-o-Dlz0UH8lsME8U4Wvc-eQ/view).) Hence we have a surjective homomorphism $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathrm{SO}_{3}(\mathbb{C})$, which can be explicitly described. Under this map, $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ acts transitively on $Q$, and (although I didn't check rigorously) the stabilizer of $e_{1}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice example!